# there are a embeddable ejb3 of JBoss, what the Embeddable EJB3 for?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I notice that there are an Embeddable EJB3 version of JBoss,

so, what's the use? what's the embeddable ejb3 container for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JBoss website:
Embeddable EJB 3.0 can be run outside of the application server in standalone applications, junit tests, Tomcat, or even other non-jboss application servers.